# How to do UIScrollView stable to fill the details

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using UIScrollView in Objective C project but i am unable to fill the details by scroll up/down. on that scrolling is not user friendly. That is not stable also.
How to do that scroll up/down stable?
Any one know then let me know.

Comment: Maybe a few pictures show more details.

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't possibly deduce what is wrong with it. My guess is that you are setting content size for that scrollview wrong which is causing the problems with scrolling. I have no idea what you mean by filling details in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

```
In scrollview u have any text fields


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y+15);
    //[self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
   // [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}
```

Comment: -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y+15);
   
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.scView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  
}